# Reset and Power buttons on the system block in Linux

Tags: linux, debian, reboot, reset, poweroff

In my Debian Linux PC the buttons Reset and Power on the system block do nothing.

Is it possible the Reset button to make a soft reboot (the same as `sudo reboot`)? Is it likewise possible the Power button to do soft poweroff (the same as `sudo poweroff`)?

---

Weird. I found that Power button works as expected in normal situations. But when XWindows is hanged (the very situation when I need the Power button), the Power button does nothing. I have the pristine Debian `/etc/acpid/` and don't understand why is it not working and how to make it works when XWindows is hanged.

Here is my config:

`/etc/acpi/powerbtn-acpi-support.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

# This script initiates a shutdown when the power putton has been
# pressed. Loosely based on the sample that ships with the acpid package.
# If the acpid sample is present as a real config file (as it was in earlier
# versions of acpid), we skip this script. (Purging and reinstalling acpid
# resolves this situation, or simply deleting /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn.)

if [ -f /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn -o -f /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn.dpkg-bak ] ; then
        logger Acpi-support not handling power button, acpid handler exists at /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn or /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn.dpkg-bak.
        exit 0
fi

[ -e /usr/share/acpi-support/policy-funcs ] || exit 0

. /usr/share/acpi-support/policy-funcs

if { CheckPolicy || HasLogindAndSystemd1Manager; }; then
        exit 0
fi

if [ -x /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh ] ; then
        # Compatibility with old config script from acpid package
        /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh
elif [ -x /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh.dpkg-bak ] ; then
        # Compatibility with old config script from acpid package
        # which is still around because it was changed by the admin
        /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh.dpkg-bak
else
        # Normal handling.
        /sbin/shutdown -h -P now "Power button pressed"
fi
```

`/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn-acpi-support`:

```
event=button[ /]power
action=/etc/acpi/powerbtn-acpi-support.sh
```

I have no other files in `/etc/acpi/`.

Comment: Weird. I found that Power button works as expected in normal situations. But when XWindows is hanged (the very situation when I need the Power button), the Power button does nothing. I have the pristine Debian `/etc/acpid/` and don't understand why is it not working and how to make it works when XWindows is hanged

Comment: Please use the `edit` link and add the information from your comment to the question.

Comment: Tell us more about the hardware and firmware -- processor, motherboard (if known), case brand, BIOS or UEFI and manufacturer, all affect the operation of power and reset buttons on the system case.

Comment: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz; Gigabyte H67A-UD3H motherboard; Award Software BIOS; NZXT case.